# Tkinter (Python 3.5): TypeError when calling `.configure` on a label object

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a `label` object that needs to display a variety of images. Based on my research, the following script (below) should successfully update the image displayed in my `label` object. However, when I call `self.ImageViewer.configure(image=self.imgToDisp)`, I get a TypeError (seen below).

I'm not entirely sure what the error means, but it looks like `.configure` is expecting a string? Nobody else seems to encounter this problem so I must be doing something syntactically wrong with the script below. Any input is appreciated.

Script:

```
def getImgs(self): 

    folderPath = filedialog.askdirectory()

    self.imgArray, self.imagePaths = batchImpt.importAllImgs(folderPath)      

    halThrThsnd.saveAllData(self.imgArray)

    im = Image.open(self.imagePaths[0])
    self.imgToDisp = PhotoImage(im)
    self.imageViewer.configure(image = self.imgToDisp)
    self.imageViewer.image = self.imgToDisp
```

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\biegad1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "//mspm1bnas50s/home58/biegad1/Python Scripts/GUI_0_1.py", line 40, in getImgs
    self.imageViewer.configure(image = self.imgToDisp)
  File "C:\Users\biegad1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1330, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\biegad1\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1321, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type TiffImageFile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `self.imgToDisp = PhotoImage(im)` to `self.imgToDisp = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)`

Of course, you must add `ImageTk` to your import statements. I think you already did: `from PIL import Image`. If So, modify it to: `from PIL import Image, ImageTk`.

Comment: Totally worked! So what is the difference in calling `PhotoImage` vs `ImageTk.PhotoImage`?

Comment: The different is that tkinter can deal only with GIF images. So writing `self.imgToDisp = PhotoImage(im)` means you are asking tkinter to deal with your image, but it can not. So you need to rely on PIL library which has the same name method `PhotoImage()` but which belongs to the module `ImageTk` @DeeWBee